# Add fields to angularfire programatically and sync with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Using AngularJS, AngularFire and Firebase, as a new user, I am having trouble with a distributed code base.  I am trying to use Factory() often to re-use code and follow best practices for tests.  However, I am having trouble adding data to my AngularFire object, and Firebase.

Given the following factory:

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory("ItemData", ["$firebaseObject", "$firebaseArray", "GetFireBaseObject",
    function($firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, GetFireBaseObject) {
        var ItemsRef = GetFireBaseObject.DataURL('Items/');
        return {
            AllItems: function() {
                return $firebaseArray(ItemsRef);
            },
            OneItem: function(ItemKey) {
                var OneItemRef = ItemsRef.child(ItemKey); 
                return $firebaseObject(OneItemRef);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

I can get my item, I can work with the data, etc...  However, I cannot seem to add an element to the object, and have it added to Firebase. While the screen will update the quantity when I call the AddQuantity/MinusQuantity, I cannot get this data to link with Firebase and update the records there.

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('InventoryCtrl', ["$scope", "StoreData", "ItemData"
    function ($scope, StoreData, ItemData) {

        $scope.StoreList = StoresData.AllStores();
        $scope.SelectedStore = {};     // Store Information
        $scope.ItemList = {};          // Store Item List

        $scope.GetItemsForStore = function() {
            // StoreDate.OneStoreItems returns list of items in this store
            var ItemData = StoreItems.OneStoreItems($scope.SelectedStore.Key);  // $firebaseArray() returned

            for( var i = 0; i < ItemData.length; ++i)
            {
                var Item = ItemData[i];

                // Item Data is master item data (description, base price, ...)
                var OneItem = ItemsData.OneItem(Item.$id);  // Get Master by Key

                Item.Description = OneItem.Description;   // From Master
                Item.UnitPrice = OneItem.UnitPrice;
                Item.Quantity = 0;
                Item.UnitTotal = 0;
            }
            $scope.ItemList = ItemData;
        };

        $scope.AddQuantity = function(item) {
            if( ! item.Quantity ) {
                item.Quantity = 0;
            }
            ++item.Quantity;
        };

        $scope.MinusQuantity = function(item) {
            if( ! item.Quantity ) {
                item.Quantity = 0;
            }
            --item.Quantity;
            if(item.Quantity <= 0) {
                item.Quantity = 0;
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Snippet from HTML

```
            <pre>{{ ItemList | json}}</pre>
            <div>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th>Extended</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="(Key, item) in ItemList">
                            <td>{{item.$id}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AddQuantity(item)">+</button></td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="MinusQuantity(item)">-</button></td>
                            <td>{{item.UnitPrice | SLS_Currency}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.UnitTotal}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I can see the Quantity field added to the ItemList object in the  element, but even though I am passing the 'item' element from the ng-repeat with the buttons, which seems to be the proper reference, I do not see the data sync to Firebase.

Comment: You load your `$firebaseObject into `OneItem`, but then modify the fields on `Item`. `var OneItem = ItemData.OneItem(Item.$id);` vs `Item.Description = OneItem.Description;`. Modify the properties on `OneItem` and then call `$save()` on it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated the code with comments to better explain what I am trying to do.  The data is normalized, and each store may have a different subset of information from the Master list of items.  The OneItem call is for the Master item, so I can get description, price, etc... from it, for my working list that I want to update. I do not want to change the master item, but the store item.

Comment: The problem remains the same as far as I can see: you need to call `$save` on a `$firebaseObject` somewhere to save your changes. If that's not it, can you set up a jsfiddle/jsbin that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I will have to try to pull it apart and create one, since I need a Firebase reference etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the factory to be a service, and I believe this could still be done via the factory, but I had to add the bind functionality from the AngularFire manual as shown.  A subset of the code is below to select the record and do an add.

```
angular.module('MyApp').service("ItemData", ["$firebaseObject", "$firebaseArray", "GetFireBaseObject",
    function($firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, GetFireBaseObject) {
        var ItemRef = GetFireBaseObject.DataURL('Items/');

        this.AddItem = function(Item) {
            var OneItemRef = ItemRef.child(Item.Key);
            OneItemRef.update(Item);
            return $firebaseObject(OneItemRef);
        };

        this.DeleteItem = function(ItemKey) {
            var OneItemRef = ItemRef.child(ItemKey);
            OneItemRef.remove();
        };      

        this.GetAllItems = function() {
            return $firebaseArray(ItemRef);
        };

        this.GetOneItem = function(ItemKey) {
            var OneItemRef = ItemRef.child(ItemKey);
            return $firebaseObject(OneItemRef);
        };
    }
]);
```

Then the controller will have to do an added bind, which could be possibly done in the service as well:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('ItemCtrl', ["$scope", "ItemData", 
    function ($scope, ItemData) {

        $scope.Items = ItemData.GetAllItems();

        $scope.EditItem = function(Item) {
            var EditItem = ItemData.GetOneItem(Item.Key);
            // Bind here for real time updates - NOTE: Changes with each key
            EditItem.$bindTo($scope, "Item").then(
                function(unbind) {
                    $scope.ItemUnbind = unbind;
                }
            );
            $scope.Item.NewField = "ABC";     // Add extra field to Firebase
        };

        $scope.SaveItem = function(Item) {
            if( ! $scope.ItemEditMode )
            {
                $scope.Item = ItemData.AddItem(Item);
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

With this change though, any changes (each key press for instance) will be immediately sync'd into the Firebase data.